# How $\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x $is differentiable

Tags: calculus

I try to use $f(x)= \frac{1}{x} $ and $g(x) = \left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}} $ . edit:for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Try to show $g \circ f$ differentiable.

I can get $f(x)$ is differentiable but I can't get $g(x)$  differentiable.

In other way I use $ f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = (x)^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$.

Have same problem It won't work on $g(x)$.

What should I do choose new $f(x),g(x)$  or prove in any other way.

Comment: Have you heard of logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: Calculating the derivative of that function basically requires you to know how to differentiate $a(x)^{b(x)}$. There is no trick around this.

Comment: Are you trying to show *differentiability* or are you trying to find an *explicit formula* for the derivative? Your question is about the former, but what you seem to be trying to do is the latter.

Comment: Maybe you want to use that $a^b=\exp(\log a^b)=\exp( b\log a)$. I think you should be able to answer your question from there on your own.

Comment: I need to show differentiability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $(1+1/x)^x$ is, by definition, $\exp(x\ln(1+1/x)).$ But we have to be careful: $\ln(1+1/x)$ is defined iff $1+1/x>0.$ I.e., iff $x\in (-\infty,-1)\cup (0,\infty)).$ On this domain, $\exp(x\ln(1+1/x))$ is the composition of differentialbe functions, hence is differentiable, and we're done. (Note that we don't need the formula for the derivative to show it's differentiable.)

Answer (score 1):

As a real function, it's not differentiable on $[-1, 0]$.

Everywhere else, the derivative is

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x = \frac{d}{dx} e^{x \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)} = \left( \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) + \frac{-x/x^2}{( 1 + \frac{1}{x})} \right)e^{x \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)} = \left( \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) - \frac{1}{x+1} \right)  \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right)^x $$

Comment: you can not build the first derivative if you want to prove that a derivative exists